# Constrain certain dimensions while resizing groups of objects

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm creating a mockup in Adobe Illustrator. I have a mockup of the Yosemite window (with the close, minimize, and fullscreen buttons) and some stuff in the main content area. The annoying this is that if I resize the mockup, the Yosemite buttons and the titlebar area get fatter. Is there a way to constrain the proportions, so that when I resize the entire screen, the titlebar will only resize in the x direction, and not in the y direction?

Here's a visual example of what I'm talking about:

[image]

Now when I resize, I get this undesirable behaviour:

[image]

The only way I've found to get around is to manually resize the content area and the titlebar area individually. Is there a better way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Use the direct select tool to select the anchor points for the title bar/window and drag them right or left. You can resize the object without effecting the other objects and anchor points.

Comment: Please see the duplicate link above your question.